# problem in reaching Grub

Tags: grub2

I forgot my root password and want to reset it by using recovery mode but as soon as am selecting recovery mode it is showing me "must be authenticated" and "press any key to continue" as soon as I press any key it is again redirecting me to the Grub options.
Am attaching the screenshots below.
So can you tell me what is the issue and how can I reset my root password.

Comment: Hello. I do not see a version of Ubuntu in your question. What version are you using? What screen shot and does it help the question? The title of the question does not match the question content.